# Node.js: pipe stream to response freezes over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use [Connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) to serve static content, but with large files (> 40KB), a first chunk of 40,960 bytes is sent (sometimes 32,940 bytes), then the transfer sleeps for 2 minutes, then the transfer finishes. I found out that it happens when I pipe a stream to the response (this is how Connect sends the response).

Here is a code the reproduces this, on Node 0.6.2, on Windows and Linux, with a 48,980 bytes file:

```
var fs = require( "fs" ), https = require("https");

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync( 'privatekey.pem' ).toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync( 'certificate.pem' ).toString();
var options = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var server = https.createServer( options,
function( req, res ) {
    var path = __dirname + "/public" + req.url;
    fs.stat(path, function(err, stat){
        if( err ) {
            res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(""+err);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                'Content-Length': stat.size});
            var stream = fs.createReadStream(path);
            stream.pipe(res);
        }
    } );
} ).listen(8364);
```

With `fs.readFile`, I cannnot reproduce :

```
var fs = require( "fs" ), https = require("https");

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync( 'privatekey.pem' ).toString();
var certificate = fs.readFileSync( 'certificate.pem' ).toString();
var options = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var server = https.createServer( options,
function( req, res ) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/public" + req.url, function(err, data){
        if( err ) {
            res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(""+err);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
                'Content-Length': data.length});
            res.end(data);
        } } );
} ).listen(8364);
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Does this work without the certificate?

Comment: It works in HTTP. Is it what you meant with "without the certificate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was this issue: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/2198

Fixed in Node 0.6.4!

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem with piping (might be related)
[Valums file-uploader on nodejs - multiple file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255807/valums-file-uploader-on-nodejs-multiple-file-upload)

Also had 2min sleeps. Didn't found solution with pipe did some workaround.