# Stream files in node/express to client

Tags: node.js, express

I want to stream content to clients which is possibly stored in db, which they would save as files.

Obviously res.download would do the job nicely, but none of the response.* functions accept a stream, only file paths.

I had a look at res.download impl and it just sets Content-Disposition header and then a sendfile.

So I could achieve this using this post as a guide.
[Node.js: pipe stream to response freezes over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257544/node-js-pipe-stream-to-response-freezes-over-https)

But it seems I would miss out on all the wrapping aspects that res.send performs.

Am I missing something here or should I just do the pipe and not worry about it - what is best practice here?

Currently creating temp files so I can just use res.download for now.

Comment: Try this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207762/how-to-use-request-or-http-module-to-read-gzip-page-into-a-string/10603029#10603029

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can stream directly to the response object (it is a Stream).

A basic file stream would look something like this.

```
function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.url==="somethingorAnother") {
    res.setHeader("content-type", "some/type");
    fs.createReadStream("./toSomeFile").pipe(res);
  } else {
    next(); // not our concern, pass along to next middleware function
  }
}
```

This will take care of binding to `data` and `end` events.

Comment: @Tim you should mark this as answered if it worked for you

Comment: Given the upvotes it seems to work for many and that includes me. Thanks!

Comment: Remeber to call `next` if `req.url !== "somethingorAnother"`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your AJAX request from the client has an appropriate 'responseType' set. for example like

```
$http({
  method :'GET',
  url : http://url,
  params:{},
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success()
```