# Cloud Functions for Firebase download from google storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I have a collection in firebase which looks something like this:

```
people: 
 -KuM2GgA5JdH0Inem6lGaddclose
   appliedTo: "-KuM1IB5TisBtc34y2Bb"
   document: "docs/837c2500-9cbe-11e7-8ac1-17a6c37e2057"
   name: "Test Testerson"
```

the document node contains a path to a file in a storage bucket. Is it possible to download this file to the client using an http firebase function. According to [Stream files in node/express to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13106096/stream-files-in-node-express-to-client) I should be able to stream to response in express. Will the google-storage [readstream](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/1.2.0/storage/file?method=createReadStream) work for this?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK has a [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage.Storage) object you can use.  It gives you an entry point into the [Google Cloud Storage SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#cloud-storage-ga) which can interact with storage buckets.

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket
```

Use this [Bucket](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/1.2.0/storage/bucket) object to upload and download files.  You should be able to use a stream to send contents to the client.