# How to download a file with Node.js from google drive api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, fs

**How to download a file with Node.js from google drive api**

I don't need anything special. I only want to download a file from a GoogleDrive, and then save it to a given directory of client.

```
app.get("/download",function(req,res){

  const p38290token = new google.auth.OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI);
    p38290token.setCredentials({ refresh_token: token.acc });
    const p38290Id = google.drive({
        version: "v3",
        auth: p38290token,
    });
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream("./test.png");
    try {
        p38290Id.files.get({
                fileId: "1daaxy0ymKbMro-e-JnexmGvM4WzW-3Hn",
                alt: "media"
            }, { responseType: "stream" },
            (err, res) => {
                res.data
                    .on("end", () => {
                        console.log("Done");
                    })
                    .on("error", err => {
                        console.log("Error", err);
                    })
               .pipe(dest); // i want to sent this file to client who request to "/download"
            }
        )
    } catch (error) {

    }

})
```

I want to do that just someone come to **[www.xyz.com/download](http://www.xyz.com/download)** and file will be download automatically

Comment: What happens with the code you have now?   You should consider a service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with this line:

```
var dest = fs.createWriteStream("./test.png");
```

You are using a file system command which is meant to interact with files on the server. Your question makes it clear that you wish for `express` to deliver the contents of the file over to the client making the HTTP request.

For that you can just use the `res` parameter of the route callback function. You declare it on this line:

```
app.get("/download",function(req,res){
```

In your case I'd remove the `dest` variable completely and simply `pipe` the file to `res` like so:

```
.pipe(dest);
```

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17818492/10290918) as well.

Comment: i went to download file at front-end side . so how can i do ??

Comment: You can test your server by making an HTTP request from any client. You can use a cli tool like `curl` or an app like Postman. If the response is what you expect it to be, kindly mark the question as answered. If you have a front end question, dig a bit and see if someone else has asked it and perhaps an answer is already available. If not, submit a new question...